# Rails cancan gem doesn't work with giving object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my cancan ability file,

`:manage, Topic` (It does not work)

but `:manage, :topic` (It does work)

Anyone knows why? Many Thanks

Comment: Can you provide details on any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

cancan expects a string or symbol, not the whole class. if you want you can also try:

```
:manage, Topic.name
```

Comment: tried it. Not work with Topic.name, still give me not authorized message.

Comment: ok, "not authorised" is something completely different to what you said above. So - why don't you edit your question (don't use comments, because formatting it awful), and add all the relevant information. Eg the error messages you are getting, the code that uses it etc. Without that information, we are stuck just guessing what might possibly be wrong. With real code we can actually see what's wrong and tell you exactly what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> still give me not authorized message.

If you're referring to the thing being unauthorized, you have to read up on how `CanCan` (now [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) works):

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

It looks like from the `CanCanCan` wiki that you can assign `Constant` names to the `can` method:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new
      can :manage, Topic, user_id: user.id
   end
end
```

If you upgrade your `Gemfile` to include the [latest version of `CanCanCan`](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan), it should work with the `Constant` name definition:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.13', '>= 1.13.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why if set `:manage， Topic` doesn't work. I accidentally put `authorize_resource :class => false` in my model class Topic.